# ¿Cómo generar un documento .docx con python-docx-template(docxtpl)?

Tags: python, django, python-docx

Estoy tratando de generar un documento `.docx` en Django, para ello estoy ocupando `docxtpl` (Python docx template) que genera documentos a través de plantillas `.docx`. Trato de generar el documento con estos datos:

```py
listaFinal = [
   [
      {
         "-":"LIBROS"
      },
      {
         "":"Responsabilidad Social de las Organizaciones (RSO): Avances y propuestas en América Latina",
         "Editorial":"Imprenta Editora Gráfica Real",
         "Año":2015,
         "Páginas":457,
         "Tipo Libro":53
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "-":"ARTICULOS"
      },
      {
         "":"Gestión universitaria ética y responsable. Indicadores de RSU  ",
         "Link Articulo":"http://www.revistalatinacs.org/13SLCS/2013_actas/170_Valarezo.pdf",
         "issn":"",
         "nombre_conferencia":"V Congreso Internacional Latina de Comunicación  Social – V CILCS – Universidad de La Laguna, diciembre 2013 "
      },
      {
         "":"Universidad Tecnica Particular de Loja. Proceso de internacionalización de la UTPL",
         "Link Articulo":"http://www.iesalc.unesco.org.ve/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1786&Itemid=1147&lang=es",
         "issn":"",
         "nombre_conferencia":""
      }
   ]
]
```

En mi `views` tengo algo como esto donde indico la dirección de mi plantilla `docx_filename.docx` y mando la data en `context`:

```py
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

def generaraDocumento(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/msword')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cv.docx"'

    doc = DocxTemplate(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/docx_filename.docx')
    context = {'listaFinal': listaFinal}

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(response)

    return response
```

Tengo una plantilla llamada `docx_filename.docx`; lo que hago es que en esta plantilla indico cómo quiero que sea el resultado. En mi plantilla `.docx` tengo esto para poder mostrar los datos en el archivo:

```
{% for lista in listaFinal %}
    {% for i in lista %}
        {% for clave, valor in i.items %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                {% if clave == '-' %} 
                    {{ clave }} 
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% if clave %}
                    {{ clave }} 
                {% endif %}  
                    {{ valor }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

El problema que tengo es cuando en `context` mando `listaFinal`, como se encuentra aquí:

```
context = {'listaFinal': listaFinal}
```

Me da un error como este:

> Exception Value: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable.

Sé que algo está mal en el `for` de mi plantilla `docx_filename.docx` a lo que intento iterar `listaFinal` pero no sé qué es. ¿Cómo puedo iterar correctamente para que se me pinte los datos en mi archivo `.docx`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por si a alguien le interesa lo pude resolver de esta forma:

```
{% for lista in listaFinal %}
    {% for i in lista %}
        {% for clave, valor in i.items() %}
            {% if loop.first  %}
                {% if clave == '-' %} 
                    {{ clave }} 
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {% if clave %}
                    {{ clave }} 
                {% endif %}  
                    {{ valor }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Al trabajar con un template `.docx` la sintaxis de algunas cosas cambian, lo que me sirvió a mí para solucionar mi problema fue cambiar lo siguiente: `{% for clave, valor in i.items %}` por esto `{% for clave, valor in i.items() %}` y `{% if forloop.first %}` por esto: `{% if loop.first  %}`

Haciendo estos cambios el documento `.docx` se generó correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Por si te interesa, he subido el siguiente video a Youtube donde lo explico todo paso a paso:

[Crear documentos Word con Python y docxtpl en español (+curso GRATIS al final!!)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBrRZGTSEAg&t=685s)

Un saludo y espero que os sirva.

Comment: tal vez en tu curso tienes como agregar imágenes en el template desde una URL? Lo he intentado de varias formas pero no lo logro hacer.

Comment: La explicación siempre debe ir _en la respuesta misma_, no como enlace externo. Los enlaces se rompen. Piénsalo: si algún lector más adelante tiene un problema similar, intenta acceder al enlace, y este ya no está disponible, ¿cómo podrá saber si la respuesta le ha sido útil o no? Pon el contenido esencial del enlace aquí mismo. Lee [answer].